# The role of か when 行こうか is not a question

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

> よし じゃあ　行こうか

When the intonation of 行こうか implies an invitation and not a question, what is the grammatical role of particle 「か」?

Comment: To Kawaguchi-san's answer I'd add that in English, invitations are often (if not usually) phrased in the form of a question. 行こうか can be translated as "shall we go?" which sounds a little more polite in English than "let's go." The nuance of the two constructions in Japanese is very similar, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"か" is adding a sense of invitation to the phrase, on top of other words that are also inviting, such as 〜う of 行こう.

行こう alone would suggest the speaker is a little more determined, and you have a little less choice in the matter.